# A problem regarding a generalization of Schwartz space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, schwartz-space

Consider a space of functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{C}$ satisfying
$$\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}|x^\alpha f(x)|<\infty, $$
for any multi index $\alpha$.

1. This space contains Schwartz space. Does this has any name?
2. Does this space contained in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n), 1\leq p\leq \infty?$ (I proved that this is true but not sure)
3. Does this space dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n), 1\leq p\leq \infty?$ (I guess this will not be true)
4. If (3) not true then will it become true if we add that the functions in the space are continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. These are the functions with "superpolynomial decay". I have not seen the whole space studied much as a whole, because it does not have particularly good regularity properties (at least, no better than Schwartz or $L^p$ spaces), but I have seen various linear subspaces with greater regularity studied more often. You can equivalently write your defining condition by saying that for every $f$ in your space and every $k \geq 1$, there exists a constant $C_{f,k} > 0$ that, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$,
   $$
   |f(x)| \leq C_{f,k} \exp(-k \log |x|)
   $$
   It's a lot easier to get work done if you have some uniform regularity, e.g. requiring that you have some uniform $C_k > 0$ such that $C_{f,k} \leq C_k$ for all $f$. Another option: there exist some $b > 0$ and some $t > 1$, such that for any $f$, there exists $C_f > 0$ with
   $$
   |f(x)| \leq C_f \exp(-b \log^t|x|)
   $$
   This kind of bound comes up a lot when estimating decay of correlations in statistical physics and dynamical systems. **Edit in response to a comment:** For example, [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0143385704000343) by Mark Holland (ETDS 25 (1), 2005, pp. 131-159). I found that paper by following a reference in a [paper](https://doi.org/10.1017/etds.2018.49) by Benoît R. Kloeckner (ETDS 40 (3), 2020, pp. 714-750), which I found by Googling "sub-polynomial decay".
2. Yes, this space is contained in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Same argument as for Schwartz space. **Edit:** not quite right, see the comments: you need measurability.
3. and 4. Since it contains Schwartz space (which is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for every $n$ and $p\in[1,\infty)$, this space is certainly dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$. It is not dense in $L^\infty$ (again, see comments; adding continuity would make it worse).

Comment: Right. How could I miss 3,4? Thanks for elaborate reply on 1. Can you please refer some research article using this space? That will be very much helpful. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @Prof.Hijibiji see the edit.

Comment: For (2) one needs measurability.

Comment: Sorry for the pedantry; $\mathcal S$ is not dense in $L^\infty$ which contains e.g. the constant $1$ function. If you adjust the topology by e.g. weighting the norm to make the behavior at infinity less important you still can't get e.g. the indicator of $[0,1]^n$ with $\mathcal S$ but the space of OP doesn't have a continuity restriction

Comment: @CalvinKhor no need to be sorry! Hopefully this stuff is useful for the OP and other readers, but the edits have definitely been useful reminders for me about things on which I've gotten sloppy.